# Bringing in multiple code parameters

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code which applies a class and offset variable and I am trying to bring in the following parameters

```
resuableAnimationFunc('header', 70, 'header-hide', 'header-show')
resuableAnimationFunc('footer', 300, 'footer-hide', 'footer-show')
```

but I cant seem to get them to work. Not sure if i'm writing the code out propery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

function reusuableAnimationFunc(elementName, offset, hideClass, showClass) {
    $animation = $(elementName);

    $(window).scroll(function(){
    ( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) ? $animation.addClass(hideClass).removeClass(showClass):
    $animation.addClass(showClass).removeClass(hideClass);
    });
}

    reusuableAnimationFunc('header', 70, 'header-hide', 'header-show')
    reusuableAnimationFunc('footer', 300, 'footer-hide', 'footer-show')

});
```

Comment: It's probably just a simple typo. Reusable is spelled two different ways in your sample code: reusuable and resuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `header` and `footer` are HTML elements, then wrap your code in DOM ready like:

```
$(function() {
   resuableAnimationFunc('header', 70, 'header-hide', 'header-show')
   resuableAnimationFunc('footer', 300, 'footer-hide', 'footer-show')
});
```

Comment: those are elements for html, not classes. the class is header-show etc. My question is more where do those lines go in my code. I've tried putting it right after my code and tried putting it in my html

Comment: Oh I see, so they are HTML tags. Have you put your function call in DOM ready like `$(function() { resuableAnimationFunct(...); })` ?

Comment: yes I have, good point though I'll update my question including that part. I just am not sure if I'm putting the parameter lines of code in the proper place. I thought I could put them right after the code but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: And your answer suggests I run another function?

Comment: You have wrapped the function `resuableAnimationFunc` on DOM ready. You need to wrap the function call in DOM ready like what I have posted above.

Comment: Right sorry, I meant putting it right outside the DOM ready function (but still in my functions.php) or in the html

Comment: I cannot help you on the php part as I am not a php developer. What I meant is your code should run after all the HTML has loaded.